# Keep a mega-menu visible until entering another anchor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, megamenu

I have a menu where I would like a sub-menu to appear as long as the user is in that menu; Much like you would find in a mega-menu.

I'm using jQuery to select the elements.

This is the markup structure:

[image]

As you can see each `<li>` i.e. `global-nav__list-item` contains an anchor which represents an element in the main navigation.

Also nested in there is the corresponding `div` element i.e. `collapsible__content` which represents the mega-menu.

I thought this script could drill down and simply add and remove the class `collapsible__content--expanded` on `collapsible__content` which would solve my problem.

```
$('.global-nav__list-item').mousemove(function() {
   $(this > '.collapsible > .collapsible_content').addClass('collapsible__content--expanded');
}, function(){
   $(this > '.collapsible > .collapsible_content').removeClass('collapsible__content--expanded');
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your selector isn't valid. You need to use `find()` when attempting to select child elements from the `this` reference: `$(this).find('.collapsible > .collapsible_content')`.

Secondly, `mousemove()` doesn't accept multiple functions. Assuming you're expecting to add/remove the class on mouseenter/mouseleave you could use `hover` instead, along with `toggleClass()`:

```
$('.global-nav__list-item').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.collapsible > .collapsible_content').toggleClass('collapsible__content--expanded');
});
```

Better still, you could use CSS alone to achieve this:

```
.global-nav__list-item .collapsible > .collapsible-content {
  display: none;
}

.global-nav__list-item:hover .collapsible > .collapsible-content {
  display: block;
}
```

The above is assuming the `.collapsible__content--expanded` is just hiding/showing content. If not, you'd simply need to copy the relevant styles in to the above.

Comment: Thanks Rory!! That didn't work. But I suspect something else must be going on! I tried: 
`$('.global-nav__list-item').hover(function(e) {
  console.log(e.,target);
  $(this).find('.collapsible > .collapsible_content').toggleClass('collapsible__content--expanded');
});`

To insure the script was being registered—And I do see the elements getting logged, but no other functionality...

Comment: Actually this works! In my `DOM` I have a style `.collapsible__content` not `.collapsible_content`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.global-nav__list-item').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('.collapsible > .collapsible_content').addClass('collapsible__content--expanded');
});
$('.global-nav__list-item').mouseout(function(){
   $(this).find('.collapsible > .collapsible_content').removeClass('collapsible__content--expanded');
})
```